# how to grab photo/photos from inside of other images

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

how to detect and grab photo/photos from inside of an image.. All I can think of is applying canny edge detection then finding contour and creating bounding box but this approach sometimes doesn't work on some images.[Like checkout this picture](https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/passport-photos-different-people-260nw-431262283.jpg) ,  [and like this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtDgc.jpg)

Comment: If you have a lot of these data, deep learning is the way to go. If you dont you can try template matching.

Comment: Is there any other way through OpenCV and python because images are different. @Meisam

Comment: Python is the world of deep learning, and "template matching" is a function of opencv. Although with opencv you can implemented your hand made version of template mathcing too. You also could read about feature matching which again is implemented in opencv.